# How can I limit when someone can view a sheet using Google Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am the programmer of my very small company and I am trying to create an online program. I am using Google products and I hope to help us be more efficient, but I am stuck right now!

What I am trying to do is make each member gets daily tasks, assigned by the manager. As they complete their tasks, they get a percent grade how much they did. That I can figure out, but the next part, I'm not too sure.

Once finish everything, I want them to be able to view other tasks that the other members have posted, but are of immediate priority. An example of would be doing concept art for a side character. By doing these tasks, they can go above 100% and get us ahead of schedule.

Also, once they finish their daily tasks, they can ahead at what they have to do for tomorrow and start doing that early too. I don't want them worrying about tomorrow's tasks, or these smaller tasks until they finished what they needed to do today.

**TL;DR**: How do I make it so someone can't view a sheet on a Google Spreadsheet until a certain variable is met, e.g 100?

Huge thanks in advance for anyone who helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Although ranges can be write protected individually there is no way to control range visibility in a spreadsheet. View access applies to the whole document.

I think the best solution would be to build a web application to show the selected data range from the spreadsheet,this way you can choose with accuracy who can see it and what he can see.

Showing spreadsheet data in a webapp is relatively simple as long as you're not making use of specific spreadsheet features. You should easily find examples and code samples all around.

Comment: Okay, that sounds pretty fair. Things have been getting pretty complicated on spreadsheets. Would I need to store all the memory and values on spreadsheets, or someother app, or can it all be stored on the scripts?